# To: infinitive marker or a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary, gerunds

I am not sure when **to** is a preposition, in these two sentences below **to** works on the same way for me, however, avoid is not in gerund.

> Use good judgment **to** avoid..
>
> It was critical **to** achieving good returns.

Why in the first sentence **to** is not a preposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "avoid" is functioning as the infinitive of a verb and not as a noun. The preposition "to" goes before (or more generally is associated with) a noun. As the word "avoid" is not a noun, the word "to" cannot be a preposition.